# How can I use reflection during Application_BeginRequest to instantitate a web service method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, asmx

During <strike>`Application_BeginRequest`</strike> any `Global.asax` or `System.Web.Services.WebService` event, is there a reliable way to instantiate or examine the intended web service method using reflection?  I need to determine what the value of attributes are on the web service being called.

I'm pretty sure the neccessary information is available in `HttpContext.Current.Request` to do this, but I'm not familiar enough with reflection syntax.

**GLOBAL ASAX**

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim InboundRequest As HttpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request

    'ASSUMING REQUEST IS FOR DemoService.asmx/ExampleMethod'

    'NEED CODE HERE TO DETERMINE '
    'WHAT THE VALUE OF THE "ScriptMethod" ATTRIBUTE IS'
End Sub
```

**WEB SERVICE**

```
<ToolboxItem(False), ScriptService()> _
Public Class DemoService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod(), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function ExampleMethod()
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

VB.Net or C# answers are welcome, I can convert as neccessary

Answer (score 0):

You could, but I think it'd be better to do whatever you are planning to do in the `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event as you'll have the web service object instance created by asp.net already. Just remember that this event is fired for all types of handlers (pages, web services, generic, etc).

If you do want to go this route on your own, then you'd just need to do Activator.CreateInstance(type) where type is the web service type.

Comment: Do you have an example of overriding that event?

Comment: you could put it in global.asax. it's just like the BeginRequest event

Comment: Can you be more specific about what I have access to during `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` that I don't have access to in  `Application_BeginRequest`?  EventArgs is still empty and I don't see anything special in Context or Request

Comment: The [Handler property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.handler.aspx) of the current context aka HttpContext.Current.Handler. The object in that property will be your web service (assuming it's a web service handler)